# Move item right or left

Tags: itemize, tcolorbox

I use texmarker with `documentclass = article`.

How can i change/move element itemize (a,b,c,d,e) to the `left` or `right`.

Thank so much.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[width=10cm]

\begin{itemize}
%\hspace*{0.2cm}
\item \small a 
\item \small b 
\item \small c 
\item \small c
\item \small e 

\end{itemize}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want to move the items with respect to the `tcolorbox` or do you want to move the whole box?

Comment: @samcarter i want only move item a,b,c,d, e to right inside tcolorbox, not move the box. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Try `\addtolength{\leftmargini}{3cm}`

Comment: @samcarter same question, but not with tcolorbox. how can move item if i use \posterbox. This code \addtolength{\leftmargini}{3cm} is ok with tclobox but not effect in \posterbox. thanks

Comment: While you wait for an answer to your new question, can you go back to your previous ones and look if the answers solve your problems and accept them, if they do?

Comment: Sorry. i have accepted all pre answer of old posts

Comment: Great to hear! Can you make a short [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that demonstrates your problem with `\posterbox`?

Comment: Changing `leftmargini` works just fine with `\posterbox`: https://pastebin.com/wNgEZy3K

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91419/discussion-between-latexforti-and-samcarter).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the `\leftmargini`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[width=10cm]
\addtolength{\leftmargini}{3cm}
\begin{itemize}
\item \small a 
\item \small b 
\item \small c 
\item \small c
\item \small e 
\end{itemize}
\end{tcolorbox}


\begin{tcbposter}[
    poster = {showframe,height=2.5cm,spacing=2mm,rows=2},
  boxes  = {beamer,colframe=blue!50!black,colback=blue!50,colupper=yellow!50},
]
    \posterbox{row=1,column=1}{First box} \posterbox{row=1,column=2,rowspan=2}{%
        \addtolength{\leftmargini}{2cm}
        \begin{itemize}
        \item \small a
        \item \small b
        \end{itemize}
    }
    \posterbox[natural height]{row=1,column=3}{Third box}
\end{tcbposter}

\end{document}
```